# What gives the Supreme Court the authority to restrict free speech?

Tags: united-states, constitution, supreme-court, freedom-of-speech

I am confused as to how they can prevent certain kinds of speech from being used. Doesn't the Constitution say it can't be limited?

Comment: *Has* the Supreme Court restricted free speech? In what way?

Comment: I think so, for example they ban speech that incites violence or defamation. I'm not sure though.

Comment: The question is too vague to answer right now. But when you edit the question to mention a specific supreme court ruling which you believe restricts freedom of speech, then we could look into their ruling and perhaps tell you what gives them the authority.

Comment: No right is absolute.

Comment: I think the down votes here are unfortunate. News reports of SCOTUS rulings on speech issues often frame them as "the court has forbidden X speech" or "The Court has permitted Y" without mentioning the law or regulation that the Court is passing on. This makes it natural to think of the Court as restricting speech in some cases.

Comment: Did you actually read the first amendment? Tell me the first 5 words please.

Comment: @user253751 I not only read it, I quoted it in my answer, and quoted Black's comments on "make no law". Note that although it says  "**Congress** shall make no law" this has been taken to prohibit actions by any part of the government that abridge free speech, including "gag orders" by Judges. I said the view of the Court as restricting speech is an error, but a not uncommon one.

Comment: @DavidSiegel I assumed user253751 was talking to the OP, not yourself. Perhaps they could clarify.

Comment: @F1Krazy I think he was asking David

Comment: A comment starting "Did you actually read..." addressed to a new contributor would be unfortunate in my view.

Answer (score 6):

### Nothing

The Supreme Court does not "restrict free speech". What it does is decide whether restrictions passed by Congress, or by a state legislature, or by some regulation, executive action, or other governmental action, violate the [First Amendment's](https://www.law.cornell.edu/constitution/first_amendment) guarantee of free speech.

That says:

> Congress shall make no law respecting an establishment of religion, or prohibiting the free exercise thereof; or abridging the freedom of speech, or of the press; or the right of the people peaceably to assemble, and to petition the government for a redress of grievances.

(The court has held that this was made applicable to the states via the Fourteenth Amendment. Prior to that it applied only to the Federal Government)

But the court has held that not all words are covered by this protection. It has said that obscenity is not protected speech, nor are "fighting words" nor is incitement to crime, nor is defamation. Whole books could be (and have been) written about just what is and is not protected speech under the First Amendment

But in none of these cases has the Court said what should be or will be restricted, only what **could** be if Congress or other legal authority chose to do so.

Justice [Hugo Black](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugo_Black#First_Amendment) famously took the view that this was absolute, that "when the first amendment said 'Congress shall make no law' it meant NO law". More formally:

> Speech is wholly 'beyond the reach' of federal power to abridge ... I do not believe that any federal agencies, including Congress and the Court, have power or authority to subordinate speech and press to what they think are 'more important interests'.

But the court as a whole has never adopted Black's view. And even Black put significant limits on what he would call "speech". He did not view expressive conduct as "symbolic speech", such as flag burning or wearing a black armband.

Comment: Meh. This a bit of legal hair splitting in that SCOTUS has defined some speech (in the common sense of the word) not to be "speech" (in the sense of the 1st Amendment). In European jurisprudence, the equivalent prestidigitation is somewhat more explicit in that human rights are balanced against each other, so speech can be restricted if it were e.g. to endanger life (the famous "scream fire in a theater" example used in the US is easily cast as a balancing test in the latter view).

Comment: In practice, the US also used some balancing tests https://www.mtsu.edu/first-amendment/article/1608/pickering-connick-test but they were apparently not happy with that and they turned these into a categorical distinction https://mtsu.edu/first-amendment/article/596/garcetti-v-ceballos

Comment: @Fizz The 1st Amendment doesn't appear to specify what "freedom of speech" means. It doesn't say "all speech should be legal". It just says "you shall have freedom of speech". The court may decide that "freedom of speech" doesn't have to mean that all speech is legal, only some speech. (You'd be hard-pressed to argue that words that come out of your mouth are not speech)